# LiveCD with puppet razor

Tags: puppet

I have a couple of servers and want to provide live cd and O/S reinstalls using razor-server from a self-coded panel.
Razor has very bad documentation and i saw only some bits of info regarding O/S installation.

Is there a way to boot bare metal server into a LiveCD iso using razor?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I use RescueCD.My `gentoo.task/boot_install.erb`

```
#!ipxe
echo Razor <%= task.label %> task boot_call
echo Installation node: <%= node_url  %>
echo Installation repo: <%= repo_url %>

sleep 3

kernel <%= repo_url("/rescue64") %> <%= render_template("kernel_args").strip %> || goto error
initrd <%= repo_url("/initram.igz") %> || goto error
boot

:error
prompt --key s --timeout 60 ERROR, hit 's' for the iPXE shell; reboot in 60 seconds && shell || reboot
```

and `gentoo.task/kernel_args.erb`,

```
vga=791 setkmap=us console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200 netboot=<%= repo_url("/sysrcd.dat") %> rootpass=<%= node.root_password %> ar_source=http://172.100.1.1:18080/autoruns
```

autoruns directory is host on DHCP server.